# What can I use to create servo type sound effects without electronics?

Tags: sound-effects, camera

I'm making a cyborg/android type costume, and I'd like to rig something to produce that servo camerafocus type (vzzt vzzt ) sound. Without electronics. What could I use?

Comment: No comments to explain the downvote?

Comment: I can only guess that it's because the question is very board, asking for a solution to an entire problem. I'll point out though that while idea-generation & tutorial questions are not on topic, questions asking for a way to tackle a problem are fine. The grey area here is that this is essentially a sound-effects question, which the community hasn't dealt with before.

Comment: It's a long standing tradition of the Stack sites that comments are not required for down votes, though it is useful when it happens. In this case, I'd hazard that it's seen as being on the edge of an Arts and Crafts question and probably on the broad side of things to boot. It's also really not clear why electronics are being ruled out, especially given that they're a pretty obvious approach to the problem...

Comment: Thanks John. When looking for a cosplay area Arts & Crafts came up the most. I'll add detail to the question.

Comment: I looked into it, and since your question is about creating a practical sound effect, you may be better off asking on [sound.se]. I know this is for a costume, but what you're really looking for is reproducing a certain type of sound.

Comment: I'll open it there instead

Answer (score 4):

Set up a hand crank, striker and two resonators as shown in the attached drawing should create the sound effect you are looking for without the use of electronics.

As you move the hand crank the axle turns the disk on which a striker has been fastened. As the striker passes the resonator (fixed in place) it will stroke the resonator to emit its characteristic sound.

Place two resonators 180 degrees apart and you should get your vzzt vzzt sound effect.

Note: you will have to play with the length and width of the resonartors to get the right sound out of it.

[image]

Comment: I'll have to look into this a bit more before I accept as the answer, but it looks good

Answer (score 0):

I remember some hand-operated tin toys with spinning parts.  Probably close.  Alternatively you might want to try some of those hand copter toys where you crank a retracting cord in order to launch a plastic wheel with blades into the air.  Just omit the copter wheel, and the springed crank should like be good for that kind of noise.  If not, gluing somethink small and floppy on the axle might help.  Don't glue the copter wheel, though: if it can't disengage, it will likely break the launcher pretty fast.